# Provisioning profile does not match bundle identifier

Tags: ios, bundle, identifier, provisioning

i have run in iphone is ok, but i try to build it and upload, it get this error, how can i fix it, thanks!

> Code Sign error: Provisioning profile does not match bundle
>   identifier: The provisioning profile specified in your build settings
>   (“PicKey Distribution”) has an AppID of “com.KKApps.PicKey” which does
>   not match your bundle identifier “com.KKApps.PicKey.MyKeyBoard”.

CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'App Extension' in SDK 'iOS 8.0'

Comment: have you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

At the creation of your Provisioning profile on the Developer Portal you have provided the app id `com.KKApps.PicKey`

Your Bundle identifier has to be strictly identical to the one you provided for the Provisioning profile, with no additions after like the `.MyKeyBoard`

**Two solutions for you**

**1.** In your case, with an explicit app ID : You change your app bundle identifier to `com.KKApps.PicKey` to match the Provisioning profile App ID

**2.** Use an You create a new App ID `com.KKApps.PicKey.*` and change the Provisioning profile to link to it (or create a new one). The * is a wildcard allowing to match multiple apps

With solution 2 you will be able to create apps with Bundle Identifier starting with `com.KKApps.PicKey.`

For exemple `com.KKApps.PicKey.MyKeyBoard`, or `com.KKApps.PicKey.MySuperApplication`

**Apple's explanations for APP IDs**

> **Explicit App ID** (Example: com.domainname.appname)
>
> If you plan to incorporate app services such as Game Center, In-App
>   Purchase, Data Protection, and iCloud, or want a provisioning profile
>   unique to a single app, you must register an explicit App ID for your
>   app.
>
> To create an explicit App ID, enter a unique string in the Bundle ID
>   field. This string should match the Bundle ID of your app.
>
> **Wildcard App ID** (Example: com.domainname.*)
>
> This allows you to use a single App ID to match multiple apps. To
>   create a wildcard App ID, enter an asterisk (*) as the last digit in
>   the Bundle ID field.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Watchkit App's Bundle Identifier to your app's bundle identifier, also change your watchkit extension's Bundle Identifier to your App's Identifier.

Also check for the Versions of your main app and watchkit, watchkit extension's versions, both versions should be same.

for more please look into apple docs
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2410/_index.html

Hope this will help!!!